daisyUI Custom Color Shades for Theme
Is there any way to add shades for daisyUI theme? like:
dark: {
          primary: {
            100: '#f5f9f3',
            200: '#ebf3e6',
            ...
          },
          'primary-focus': '#48604f',
          'primary-content': '#272525',

When I use btn-primary-100, it does not work. Any solution?
This is my Full tailwind.config.js file:
  dark: {
          primary: '#cde2c1',
          'primary-focus': '#48604f',
          'primary-content': '#272525',

          secondary: '#48604f',
          'secondary-focus': '#f9e1e1',
          'secondary-content': '#cde2c1',

          accent: '#e9e7e7',
          'accent-focus': '#d1cccc',
          'accent-content': '#2a2e37',

          neutral: '#2a2e37',
          'neutral-focus': '#16181d',
          'neutral-content': '#ffffff',

          'base-100': '#23351e',
          'base-200': '#243b1d',
          'base-300': '#1d2c19',
          'base-content': '#cde2c1',

          info: '#66c7ff',
          success: '#87cf3a',
          warning: '#e1d460',
          error: '#ff6b6b',

          '--rounded-box': '1rem',
          '--rounded-btn': '.5rem',
          '--rounded-badge': '1.9rem',

          '--animation-btn': '.25s',
          '--animation-input': '.2s',

          '--btn-text-case': 'uppercase',
          '--navbar-padding': '.5rem',
          '--border-btn': '1px'
        },

I tried every possible solution, unfortunately no luck so far.
The only workaround I have found is using theme - extend. Like:
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          100: "#f5f9f3",
          200: "#ebf3e6",
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },

But with this, I have to use btn bg-primary-600 text-primary-content. I want to use btn- classname.

The derivateives seem to be declared statically so there is no dynamic way of adding more. You'd have to write extra classes yourself.

Yes, that's another workaround but not a solution that i am looking for. Thanks, heaps.
